# How to connect two bluetooth speakers simultaneously via "Virtual Audio Cable"?

Tags: audio, windows-10, bluetooth, speakers, multicast

I have two speakers that I need to connect wirelessly via bluetooth. These are standard aux/usb speakers, and presently I've connected one of the speakers via 3.5mm jack to my windows 10 laptop. I have a bluetooth USB Dongle, that allows an aux output to my speakers to play music via bluetooth.

[image: Bluetooth Dongle - Image]

Can I connect my second speaker via a similar new dongle and place it in another room while playing music via both the speakers wirelessly/bluetooth?

I read online that there's a software called "[Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm)" that allows this, but I haven't used this software and don't know how it functions... There's no guide provided on their website, and it has to be purchased while I was looking for a free alternative.

I need to listen to music from my laptop on two bluetooth devices simultaneously, on Windows 10. Is this possible?

Comment: Don't know how to answer your Bluetooth question, but you can use http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/index.htm as a free alternative to Virtual Audio Cable - they're donation supported. I'd also recommend their Voicemeeter application to set everything up.

Comment: Thanks Tomysshadow! I'll try the alternative you've suggested... I hope it supports bluetooth too!

Comment: Hi Tomysshadow: I'm looking for an answer to a [similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/1022662/how-to-reconnect-bluetooth-headphones-automatically-and-enable-voicemeter-re-en). Please could you help?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get two different 
brands of Bluetooth speakers to work at the same time using this method and it didn't cost me anything.

I am using software on my windows 10 laptop that will allow me to connect two Bluetooth speakers at once.
 It is donation-ware called Voice Meeter. It was 
originally designed to mix audio with microphone during a live broadcast or recording.

After installation I right clicked on the speaker icon in the system tray 
and selected "Playback Devices".

I then selected Voice Meeter and made it the default audio device (When you are done using it, you can switch it off by setting 
its properties to disabled. Also, right click in the playback window and make sure "Show Disabled Devices" is checked so you can find it to set it back to 
default when you need it again).

Open the Voice Meeter program 
and ignore the first three columns and just look at the forth column "Hardware Out".

Set A1 to one of your speakers and set A2 to the other speaker.
If you only have one Bluetooth speaker then set A1 to your computers speaker and A2 to your Bluetooth speaker.

In this case you will need to set a delay to A1 to sync with the delay the Bluetooth speaker has or you will hear the Bluetooth speaker echo the computer 
speakers. To do that go to menu then click "system setting / options". In the area that says OUT A1 set the delay to about 200ms.