# How to reconnect Bluetooth Headphones automatically, and enable voicemeter re-enable?

Tags: audio, windows-10, bluetooth, speakers, audio-streaming

I purchased the Kinivo BTH240 Bluetooth Headphones lasst year (2015), and have been listening to audio via both laptop (windows 10) and iphone (ios9).

Recently I had asked about how to [How to connect two bluetooth speakers simultaneously via “Virtual Audio Cable”?](https://superuser.com/questions/1003510/how-to-connect-two-bluetooth-speakers-simultaneously-via-virtual-audio-cable), and found out about `VB-Cables & Voicemeter` apps that let you connect multiple devices input to multiple outputs both virtual and hardwares...

I intially tried getting the voicemeter to run, but couldn't understand how to use it. Today, I installed voicemeter, [cable A+B](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/index.htm), and then added Cable A to speakers, and Cable B to my bluetooth headphones (while the headphones were connected). I started play, and the audio was heard both on my speakers and headphones. This was atleast something I required. Although I couldn't mute output 1 or 2 separately. Only output 1 was being muted and that muted the other output too! ie, muting speaker output muted headphones too! So I've currently switched back to speakers as my default, and am asking for help here..

I've searched for bluetooth hubs, audio powerlines (similar to wifi, although for audio), and [bluetooth audio adapters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSWPgm.jpg)... Hubs and powerlines are costly and unavailable, while the audio adapters aren't...  therefore I'm looking for a way to connect 2 separate speakers and 1 bluetooth headphones via windows 10 bluetooth on my laptop.

My problem is that on Windows 10, the bluetooth device doesn't connect automatically. There's no connect button to the settings too! Initially I had this automatically, but sometimes recently the bluetooth headphones don't connect automatically. And today after installing the voicemeter, I had to go to `volumecontrol>(rightclick)>playbackDevices>kinivo(rightclick)>connect` to connect to the bluetooth device! I believe uninstalling the voicemeter would re-enable the automatic connection. Although I need to stream three audio devices at once! If that's not possible (cause voicemeter only allows 2 outputs), then I'm good with just the speakers and headphones too!

The problem is: Once I disconnect the headphones from the computer, the CABLE-B autochanges to "default device" and doesn't revert to "Bluetooth Headphones" when I connect the headphones back again!

If this question is too complex, then to broaden the question:

I need to connect to the bluetooth device via a button. Windows 10 doesn't provide a connect button. Also, is there any multicast software for bluetooth devices?

Comment: You should set Voicemeeter Input/Voicemeeter Output as your default device, and use it to handle where the audio is going to. Under Hardware Out, set A1 to the speakers and A2 to the headphones. If you want to disable the headphones, go to A2 and choose -remove device selection-. Then set the far left column in VoiceMeeter to your microphone, and the column next to it to CABLE-A or CABLE-B (you really only need one).

Comment: Thanks! I think that would solve the issue. I got a blue screen dump when I disconnected the headphones on first attempt on my previous installation! Guess I'll try cable a/b on hardware input instead...

Comment: Make sure you're either using WDM or KS for the hardware inputs/outputs, they are the fastest and will have less latency than MME.

Comment: ok. I was using WDM only, cause I thought the full form stands for "Windows Digital Media", so I was guessing it will be the default + voicemeter also listed it on the top of the list.

Comment: No, Windows has three different APIs for audio playback. MME is the oldest and slowest but kept around for compatibility reasons. KS stands for Kernel Sound and uses the kernel. WDM is the newest which you should use if possible. There's also ASIO (only on high end professional sound cards) and WASAPI (Windows Vista's API with no advantage over WDM)

Comment: ok. Thanks! I've heard about ASIO too, although it wasn't listed in the voicemeter's connected devices.

Comment: Only Output A1 can be connected to ASIO device (used as main audio device) and routing can be done in System Settings Dialog Box to route ASIO input channels to Voicemeeter hardware inputs or to route BUS A2 / A3 to any output channel too...

Answer (score 1):

Voicemeeter user manual can help:
http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/Voicemeeter_UserManual.pdf

It's better to use Voicemeeter output A1 & A2 to send audio to 2x audio devices directly (than using intermediate Cable).

Note your can send audio to iOs Device with VBAN (instead of bluetooth), get link to VBAN receptor for iOS on this page:
http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/vban.htm